# value.format is not a funtion when using react componet timepicker

Tags: reactjs, timepicker

I try to use timepicker to change some value like

```
shutdown:{
Sunday : "18:00:00"
Monday : "20:00:00",
}





handleTimeChange(name, value){
      var shut = this.state.shutdown;
      shut[name] = value && value.format("HH:mm:ss");
      console.log(value && value.format("HH:mm:ss"));
      this.setState({
          shutdown : shut
      })
  }



<TimePicker value={this.state.shutdown.Monday} onChange = {this.handleTimeChange.bind(this,"Monday")} />
```

But I got error : value.format is not a function

How can I fix this problem

Reference https://github.com/react-component/time-picker/blob/master/examples/value-and-defaultValue.js

Comment: You might getting value in first parameter which is `name`

Comment: run a debugger and look at what types `name` and `value` are

Comment: do you get `name` as `Monday`, though?

Comment: njzk8 yes. I want to change the value of Monday

Comment: By the way, your state setting is not correct either, you need to use immutable operations.

Answer (score 0):

React passes the event object to the event handler always. So you can use the event object to access the value.

Change your code to:

```
handleTimeChange(name,event){
var value = event.target.value;
.....
}
```

Here, name is "Monday" in your case(the  parameter to the event handler)

Comment: sorry i just want to reply I tried your method but get the same error :(

1.Failed prop type: Invalid prop value of type string supplied to Panel, expected object. 2.Uncaught TypeError: value.format is not a function

the first error means I need to input string type and I input object?

Comment: Yes in value you need to suuply a moment () object as moment(this.state.shutdown.Monday, "HH:mm:ss") and remov the format in handleTimeChange()