# value.format is not a function in react js while formatting the dates

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting this error while trying to modify the values in the following ways

```
const columns = [
    { label: 'Title', key: 'title' },
    { label: 'Start', key: 'start_time',format: (value, { all_day }) => <span className="start-time">{value.format(timeFormat(all_day))}</span>},
    { label: 'End', key: 'end_time'},
    { label: 'Status', key: 'status', format: (value) => <Status status={value} /> }
  ]
```

and this is throwing an error I have mentioned.
where `timeFormat` is

`const timeFormat = (allDay) => allDay ? 'MM/DD/YYYY' : 'MM/DD/YYYY [@] h:mma`'

Although I am using the same at other positions where it is working fine. Please help where I am doing wrong. I am getting this error while formatting the dates means while showing data in a table this shows the error.

Comment: Edit your question and include all the required information for a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: what is the value's value?

Comment: I think you have confused Java `format` with JS. cause your method is ambiguous inside span

Comment: its a date "2019-01-16T05:00:00.000Z"

Comment: no @Amir-Mousavi I am using same in other places too

Comment: or is there any other way to format date.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51016381/value-format-is-not-a-funtion-when-using-react-componet-timepicker I checked here but not a worthy one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.format()` is part of [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/typescript/) so you should include it in your app then use it:

```js
const value = "2019-01-16T05:00:00.000Z";
const timeFormat = (allDay) => allDay ? 'MM/DD/YYYY' : 'MM/DD/YYYY [@] h:mma'
console.log(moment(value).format(timeFormat()))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```